# how to remove laravel_through_key in my hasManyThrough relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a hasManythrough relation. As following:

```
public function contacts(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(ContactContent::class, Content::class,"id",'as_parent_content_id','as_parent_content_id','id');
}
public function getSupportElementsAttribute(){
    return [
        "contacts" => $this->contacts,
        "documents" => $this->documents,
        "assignments" => $this->assignments
    ];
}
```

This return like this:

```
"contacts": [
                {
                    "id": 66,
                    "as_parent_content_id": 5074,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-30 16:21:11",
                    "updated_at": "2020-09-30 16:21:11",
                    "create_user_id": 1,
                    "laravel_through_key": 5074
                }
            ],
```

How to remove this laravel_through_key ?

Comment: May be you want to hide this column from collection? Then `$user = User::with('posts')->get();
$user->makeHidden('laravel_through_key');` now `laravel_through_key` will be hidden from collection. Alternative solution : add 'laravel_through_key' on your model `$hidden` attribute

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can add protected property to model

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

```php
  /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
       'laravel_through_key'
    ];
```

or you can use `makeHidden()`

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-makeHidden

```php
public function getSupportElementsAttribute(){
    return [
        "contacts" => $this->contacts->makeHidden('laravel_through_key'),
        "documents" => $this->documents,
        "assignments" => $this->assignments
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

May be you want to hide this column from collection? Then :

```
$user = User::with('posts')->get();
$user->makeHidden('laravel_through_key');
```

Now `laravel_through_key` will be hidden from your collection.

**Alternative solution** : add `laravel_through_key` on your model's `$hidden` attribute, as :

```
protected $hidden = [
    'laravel_through_key'
];
```